# I cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-typing, gradio

I am new to Python and found the following error like that. I would really appreciate your comments. Thanks
[I try to import Gradio library as gr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx9Fk.png)

I've tried several existing suggestions, but the results are in vain. I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you give us a snippet of code that you tried to run? And the traceback error you received?

Comment: I saw the link to the image you posted.  Are you sure those packages are installed in your environment, e.g. `pip install gradio typing-extensions` ran from the command line or equivalent?

Comment: This requires [`typing_extensions >= 4.6.0`](https://github.com/python/typing_extensions/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#release-460-may-22-2023), you likely have an older incompatible version. I suspect you are using `pip` unrelated to jupyter installation, see [this issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7106) for details. It does not fail for me on a clean install. To confirm, quit the notebook and try importing from python REPL.

Answer (score 2):

If your are on colab just restart your runtime and then run the code line again.
Note: When ever you install gradio restart your runtime. 
Install gradio as: 
**!pip install jiwer** 
**!pip install gradio typing-extensions**