# cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' while importing gradio in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gradio

While trying to import gradio as gr in google colab it presents the error cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions'.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

I have pip installed both gradio and Ihave tried with typing-extensions version 4.6.0 to 4.9.0 but the error still remains.

```
!pip install gradio 
!pip install typing-extensions
```

```
import gradio as gr
```

I expected a gradio interface to appear.

[Image example of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il7WW.png)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/816 Fix: Upgrade to Python 3.11 (reason unknown). Duplicate of [I cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77450322/i-cannot-import-name-typealiastype-from-typing-extensions)  (has no answer)

Comment: Can you check manually: `import typing_extensions; typing_extensions.__version__` ? Depending on jupyter setup it could be that it might wrong pip. See also https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7106 environment issues with Jupyter.

Comment: @Daraan the typing_extensions version is Version: 4.9.0